# Update WooCommerce Subscriptions billing email address when user updates their wordpress user email address

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

When a user updates their wordpress email address found on their Account Details page (found at /my-account/edit-account ), how would I automatically also update their WooCommerce Subscriptions billing email address please?

Note that I am referring to the billing account email address for WooCommerce **Subscriptions** (so that future subscription renewal email orders get changed etc), not just their WooCommerce order email address, in case that matters.

UPDATE: I finally figured this out...see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out; tested and works.  See comments within:

```
// When user updates their wordpress profile email, change 1) WooCommerce billing account email and 
// 2) active WooCommerce Subscriptions billing email to all match

add_action( 'profile_update', function( $user_id, $old_user_data ){
    $old_user_email = $old_user_data->data->user_email;
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $new_user_email = $user->user_email;

    // check if old and new email are not the same
    if ( $new_user_email !== $old_user_email ) {
        // update woocommerce billing email address to match user's wordpress email address
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $new_user_email );

        // now loop through the user's woocommerce subscriptions to find the active subscription(s)
        $users_subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user_id );
        foreach ($users_subscriptions as $subscription){
            if ( $subscription->has_status(array('active')) ) {
                // update the billing email for the active subscription as this is where the email address will be taken for future renewal orders
                update_post_meta( $subscription->get_id(), '_billing_email', $new_user_email );

                // per WooCommerce support, it is not necessary to update the billing email for the parent order of the active subscription, but here is how it would be done if desired
                // $active_sub = wcs_get_subscription( $subscription->get_id() );
                // update_post_meta( $active_sub->get_parent_id(), '_billing_email', $new_user_email );
            }
        }
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```